# oData operation consumption with objective-C

Tags: objective-c, wcf, call, odata, operation

I have a really simple WCF service operation GetCurrentBalance. It returns a decimal.

I also have the odatagen generated entity files included in the project, which contains an implementation of the GetCurrentBalance operation returning a string. Calling this method returns me an XML string with the desired value in it.

I also tried using executeServiceOperation method in the generated class and pass in the operation name as a parameter, the returned value again is the same XML string.

Is there a way to extract this value? Or do I have to write a custom parser for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without further informations, if the returned value is a formatted XML string you may try extracting the value using XPath queries, have a look at [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html) to get you started